# How to extract sheet from *.xlsm and save it as *.csv in Python?

Tags: python, excel, csv, spreadsheet, xlsm

I have a *.xlsm file which has 20  sheets in it. 
I want to save few sheets as *.csv (formatting loss is fine) individually.
Already tried xlrd-xlwt and win32com libraries but could not get through.
Can anybody please provide a code snippet which does the above processing in Python? I have other python dependencies so no other language would work.
Thanks

Comment: As far as I remember, all recent Microsoft Office formats were XML packed into Zip container. So probably you could take a look at the .xlsm file sources, clarify its XML structure and then extract required fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[xlrd](http://www.python-excel.org/) should work fine on xlsm files as well. I tested the code with a random xlsm file, and it worked perfectly.

```
import csv
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xlsx')
for sheet in workbook.sheets():
    with open('{}.csv'.format(sheet.name), 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(sheet.row_values(row) for row in range(sheet.nrows))
```

---

If you've encoding issues, try the code below:

```
import csv
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xlsm')
for sheet in workbook.sheets():
    if sheet.name == "Sheet_name_from_xlsm_file":
        with open('{}.csv'.format(sheet.name), 'wb') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            for row in range(sheet.nrows):
                out = []
                for cell in sheet.row_values(row):
                    try:
                        out.append(cell.encode('utf8'))
                    except:
                        out.append(cell)
                writer.writerow(out)
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, you should upload your data file if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet!

I am getting this error:
writer.writerows(sheet.row_values(row) for row in range(sheet.nrows))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb5' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Is there a way to specify encoding here?

Sorry, can't upload the file here.

Comment: @iPirate I think you need to encode the strings with utf8 or something similar. Try cp1252 if it doesn't work. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried to use this code to convert an .xlsm file to csv and nothing happens - no errors and it doesn't write anything out that I can see.. what could be happening. I also dont' understand where the csv is getting written out to in the above code

Comment: @kflaw: The output is saved in _<sheet_name>.csv_ (without the brackets obviously). This file will be located the place you run your script from. If you have any further questions, I advise you to open a new question here at SO, with as much context provided as possible. You can link to your new question here if you want to.

Comment: Please keep in mind, that from the current xlrd-version onwards (2.0+) explicitly only "xls"  is allowed as a file format. So for opening "xlsm"-files you have to switch to the much better openpyxl module.

Answer (score 4):

#### You can do this easily with pandas

1. Install **pandas** and **xlrd** dependencies by following

   - pip3 install pandas
   - pip3 install xlrd (required by pandas)
2. Now simply read xlsm file using **read_excel**. Here is a demo:-

```
import pandas as pd

# YOU MUST PUT sheet_name=None TO READ ALL CSV FILES IN YOUR XLSM FILE
df = pd.read_excel('YourFile.xlsm', sheet_name=None)

# prints all sheets
print(df)

# prints all sheets name in an ordered dictionary
print(df.keys())

# prints first sheet name or any sheet if you know it's index
first_sheet_name = list(df.keys())[0]
print(first_sheet_name)

# prints first sheet or any sheet if know it's name
print(df[first_sheet_name])

# export first sheet to file
df[first_sheet_name].to_csv('FirstSheet.csv')

# export all sheets 
for sheet_name in list(df.keys()):
   df[sheet_name].to_csv(sheet_name + 'Sheet.csv')


# USE IT IN MULTIPLE WAYS #
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd

import xlrd

import openpyxl #required for xlrd 2.0.1 and higher

df = pd.read_excel('your_excel_file_name.xlsm', sheet_name='your_sheet_name')
df.to_csv('your_new_name.csv')
```